# Webclient map nested object

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using WebClient to consume ai API

The node I need from the response is nested inside

example API response

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 129,
        "countries": [
            {
                "country": "Albania",
                "code": "AL",
                "flag": "https:\/\/media.api-football.com\/flags\/al.svg"
            },
            {
                "country": "Algeria",
                "code": "DZ",
                "flag": "https:\/\/media.api-football.com\/flags\/dz.svg"
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

I only need to map each country to a POJO but the only way I was able to do it so was by composing complex objects in order to achieve the same representation as to the API response.

```
public class CountryResponse {
    private Countries api;
}

public class Countries {
    private int results;
    private List<Country> countries;
}

public class Country {
    private String country;
    private String code;
    private String flag
}
```

And then I call the API

```
CountryResponse countryResponse = webClient
            .get()
            .uri("countries")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(CountryResponse.class)
            .block();
```

I would like to avoid the need for creating very complex objects only to be able to map a given node inside the JSON response from the API

Comment: Which are the *very complex objects* here in your opinion?

Comment: When i say complex object is when i need to compose more than i need. See in this example i would like to only map the response to Country objects

Answer (score 1):

> I only need to map each country to a **POJO** but the only way I was able
>   to do it so was by composing **complex objects**

Pardon me but I fail to see any complex objects provided in your example. On the contrary a POJO is the simplest object there is in the language. It's just a data container without any behavior.

So what you're doing is fetching some data from an API and flesh it out in POJOs in order to use them in your application. I see nothing wrong with that.

Now, if you want to simplify so bad you could do something about `Countries.results` since you may obtain that information from `Countries.countries.Size()`, but again I'm not sure if it's worth the effort or if it's going to put you in more trouble.